# Drupal 7 Field API min_resolution setting not applied

Tags: entities, media

In my MODULENAME.install file I create some custom content types. I add some fields to these content types with the Field API. The fields are added correctly and I can use the content types as I expect. The only problem I'm facing is that I cannot get an image field to validate the minimum resolution. I can set this through the admin UI, but I am not able to achieve this through code.

The following code constructs the field:

```
$field = array(
'field_name' => 'featured_image',
    'type' => 'image',
'settings' => array(
    'min_resolution' => '920x370'
)
);

field_create_field($field);

$field_instance = array(
'field_name' => 'featured_image',
'entity_type' => 'node',
'bundle' => $type->type,
'label' => t('Afbeelding'),
'widget' => array(
    'type' => 'image_image'
),
'instance_settings' => array(
    'min_resolution' => '920x370'
)
);

field_create_instance($field_instance);
```

Like I said before, the image field is created, but the minimum resolution is being ignored. Going through the Drupal documentation isn't helping me much.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I found the solution by doing a search on the Drupal source:

```
$field_instance = array(
'field_name' => 'featured_image',
'entity_type' => 'node',
'bundle' => $type->type,
'label' => t('Afbeelding'),
'required' => TRUE,
'settings' => array(
    'min_resolution' => '920x370'
),
'widget' => array(
    'type' => 'image_image',
)
);
```

(Couldn't answer my own question yet, hence the update)